# passing values in the a href tag of jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

Is there any other way of attaching values in a href tag of jquery mobile aside from attaching it to the ur(e.g.,`proj.html#page?ID=1`);

I tried:

```
<a href="#restaurants" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="left" id="resto" value="x">Restaurants</a>
```

but its not working.And how do I get the value in the other page?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to pass variables to a HTML page is via the URL with query parameters like you have there: `page.html?variable=value&etc=1`

The only *vaguely* stateful information you get on the web is the referer, (which tells you the URL which referred the client to the current page), but relying on that is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send information to another internal page element, any javascript variables are still accessable (because you are on the same html page). As well, any linking to files on the same site (ie example.com/test to example.com/test2) uses "Hijax" to display the next page. Because it does not load a new page (it inserts the new page into the current DOM) the javascript variables you created on the previous page are still accessible to the next page (also note that no javascript from the next page is loaded).

In order to load the next page fresh, you have to include data-rel="external" in the link/anchor tag. This means that you will not get the nice transistion that jquery mobile provides, but it will load all of the scripts and clear out the current page. This situation is the only case where you should need to be passing variables as query parameters.